# Move a specific file from one folder to another on Windows 10 in specific periods by using script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know I can use the below code to move all files from a source folder to a destination folder but how would I do this within a specific period of time. For example, I want to copy files from a folder into another folder every day at 2:00am. How can I do this with a script?

```
echo off
set X=<days>
set "source=C:\<Source Folder Path>"
set "destination=D:\<Destination Folder Path>"
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /mov /minage:%X%
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do something periodically in Windows, using a script, I would give you following advise:

- Write a script which does what you need to do.
- Configure task scheduler to run the frequency and time table of your choice: adding this to the script itself is not a good idea (imagine you restart your computer and you have forgotten to re-launch your script, then it won't be executed again).

Comment: can you tell me how can I do this without task scheduler?